# Would MVC call Dispose if your ViewModel was IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, idisposable

Suppose you do not have control over object creation and disposal. There are some circumstances where you don't.

Take the instance of MVC. Suppose you had something like this:

```
interface IFoo : IDisposable { }

class HomeController
{
    private IFoo _foo = null;

    HomeController(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_foo);
    }
}
```

Once your object is passed to the View, you pretty much lose control over it.

In this case, I can only think of two ways to mitigate this scenario:

1) If it hurts, don't do it. In other words, don't let what you give to your views be `IDisposable`s.

2) Or, same as 1 but if you do receive an `IDisposable` and you want to pass it to the view, don't pass the `IDisposable` as such. Cast, even if it involves a copy of all data, to something that's not `IDisposable` and call the `Dispose()` yourself. For e.g. like so:

```
ActionResult Index()
{
    using(_foo)
    {
      return View((FooViewModel)_foo);
    }
}
```

But I am curious. Does MVC check for `IDisposable` and call it on any state received by the View once it is done rendering the View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC `Controller` class already implements `IDisposable`. If you have further cleanup that needs done after the request executes, you can override the `Dispose` method. In your example, it would look something like:

```
public class HomeController
{
    private IFoo _foo = null;

    // Your code as usual
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if(disposing && _foo != null)
            _foo.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

Comment: go away justin, this is my question! :p

Comment: :-) 4 minutes to count!

Comment: BTW, justin is correct in that you can do this manually in each controller, but i'd still recommend just letting your ioc framework do it (for various reasons). either way gets the job done, so pick whichever works best for you.

Comment: @DarrenKopp. It's really a tie between the two of you. I appreciate both the answers. I like both of them so much that I wish I could do both. Alas! :-)

Comment: I agree with @DarrenKopp, because `HomeController` does not have _foo exclusively, but _foo is injected using constructor. This means that the instance(_foo) can be used in other instances. So I think that HomeController shouldn't dispose...

Answer (score 3):

So, there's a few things here. Short answer: **no, MVC will not call Dispose on your view model that's stored in a field**.

Longer answer: **from what you have listed here, probably**.

I'm assuming you are using a some sort of dependency injection framework like autofac, structuremap, etc, then the container will be tracking that instance. I don't know the intricacies of each framework, but I'd assume that many of them do in fact call dispose on your types that implement `IDisposable` at the end of the request (autofac does for sure).

In the end, you'll just need to **test whether it is or not** and go from there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I was hoping to go with Unity. I know there's a ContainerLifeTimeManager or some such object that controls object life-time nbut I don't know the specifics. So, I gather your answer is the right answer. 6 minutes before I can mark it.

Comment: Your Model won't automatically be disposed, but in the original answer, you can clean up after yourself by overriding the Controller's `Dispose()` method.

Comment: Sorry, @Darren. Your answer is damn right and was very helpful and opened up another topic. But I am now inclined to vote for Justin's answer as the right one as it is bang on the topic.

Comment: Oh sure. Now you're just getting all your friends to come and upvote you. :-P